# Error: redefinition of class, despite using include guards

Tags: c++, class, constructor, arduino, function-definition

I'm a javascript/typescript developer but newbee to Arduino/c++

I have a class (see h and cpp below) and have this compiler error:

```
DotMatrix.cpp:13:1: error: redefinition of 'DotMatrix::DotMatrix(uint8_t, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)'
 DotMatrix::DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
 ^
In file included from sketch/DotMatrix.cpp:5:0:
DotMatix.h:10:3: error: 'DotMatrix::DotMatrix(uint8_t, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t, uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)' previously defined here
   DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
   ^
exit status 1
```

and I don't understand why...

Here are the files:

DotMatix.h:

```
#ifndef DotMatrix_h
#define DotMatrix_h

#include <MD_MAX72xx.h> 
#include <MD_Parola.h> 

class DotMatrix
{
  public:
    DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
    : _parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices)
    {};

    void setup();
  
  private:
    MD_Parola _parola;
};

#endif
```

DotMatix.cpp:

```
#ifndef DotMatrix_cpp
#define DotMatrix_cpp

//#include <stdint.h>
#include "DotMatix.h"
#include "Arduino.h"

#include <MD_Parola.h>  // Parola library to scroll and display text on the display (needs MD_MAX72xx library)  https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_Parola
#include <MD_MAX72xx.h> // Library to control the Maxim MAX7219 chip on the dot matrix module   https://github.com/MajicDesigns/MD_MAX72XX

const int FRAME_DELAY = 25;

DotMatrix::DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
: _parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices)
{
  //MD_Parola(MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t mod, uint8_t csPin, uint8_t numDevices = (uint8_t)'\001')
  _parola = MD_Parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices);  
}

void DotMatrix::setup()
{
  this->_parola.begin();
  _parola.displayClear();
  _parola.displaySuspend(false);
  byte i = 3;                                            //EEPROM.read(0);
  _parola.setIntensity(i);                               // Values from 0 to 15
  _parola.setTextEffect(PA_SCROLL_LEFT, PA_SCROLL_LEFT); //in and out effect
  _parola.displayScroll("Hallokes ...", PA_LEFT, PA_SCROLL_LEFT, FRAME_DELAY);
}

#endif
```

For reference, this is (a snippet of) the ino file calling the class:

```
#include "DotMatix.h"

// Define the number of 8x8 dot matrix devices and the hardware SPI interface
#define MAX_DEVICES 4
#define HARDWARE_TYPE MD_MAX72XX::DR1CR0RR0_HW

#define CLK_PIN   14 //D5
#define DATA_PIN  13 //D7
#define CS_PIN    2  //D4


DotMatrix dotMatrix(MAX_DEVICES, HARDWARE_TYPE, CLK_PIN, DATA_PIN, CS_PIN);

void setup() {
  dotMatrix.setup();
}

void loop() {
}
```

I'm using the VS Code IDE with the Arduino Extension.

Comment: `#ifndef DotMatrix_cpp
#define DotMatrix_cpp` no, source files do not have include guards. You have defined two `DotMatrix::DotMatrix` functions. The error even tells you where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined the constructor twice. The first one definition of `DotMatrix` is within the class definition itself in the header `DotMatix.h`:

```
class DotMatrix
{
  public:
    DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
    : _parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices)
    {};
    //...
```

Note that the null statement `;` after the constructor definition is redundant.

This definition defines an inline function.

Pay attention to that the constructor has unused parameters.

The second definition of the constructor `DotMatrix` is within the module `DotMatix.cpp`:

```
DotMatrix::DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
: _parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices)
{
  //MD_Parola(MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t mod, uint8_t csPin, uint8_t numDevices = (uint8_t)'\001')
  _parola = MD_Parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices);  
}
```

Moreover this definition contains a redundant assignment of the data member `_parola` within the body of the constructor.

Remove entirely this definition of the constructor in the module `DotMatix.cpp`.

And these guard directives

```
#ifndef DotMatrix_cpp
#define DotMatrix_cpp
```

do not make great sense because modules are not designed to be included in other modules.

Answer (score 1):

```
void func(); // function declaration
void func() { blablabla; } // function definition.
```

You may see the simple difference between a definition and declaration. One has `{`, the other does not. A (global) function may be *defined* only once in a codebase, not twice. Otherwise your compiler will not know which function to choose - the first one? The second one?

You did:

```
// in DotMatix.h:
DotMatrix(blablaa)
{}; // yes this is definition
```

and also did:

```
// in DotMatrix.cpp
DotMatrix::DotMatrix(ublabla, who cares)
{ // also definition
```

The compiler sees two definitions of the same function and exits with an error.

Include guards are typically used to protect against including *the same file* twice. Your multiple definitions are in multiple files. Also include guard in a source file are not needed - source files are not meant to be included, so they will always be processed once.

Answer (score 0):

You shall change this line of DotMatrix.h:

```
  DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
    : _parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices)
    {};
```

It should be:

```
   DotMatrix(uint8_t maxDevices, MD_MAX72XX::moduleType_t hardwareType, uint8_t clkPin, uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t csPin) 
        : _parola(hardwareType, csPin, maxDevices);
```

If not, you are  implementing the constructor directly in header file (constructor doing nothing). The implementation being "{}" (nothing to be done)
Then when compiler sees the other implementation (the correct one) in .cpp file, it says it has already been defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the input!
I've deleted the constructor in the cpp file and all is working now.
Also the include guard in the cpp file was indeed a stupid thing to do!

Coming from js / typescript, this whole header file and weird *initialiser list* syntax is still creating shortcuts in my head ;-)

About that initialiser list: is this the only way to declare a variable of a class with a constructor with parameters? This is looking so weird to me ...